# substring using python based on key word and fixed length

Tags: python, substring

I have a very long string, and this is just part of it:

```
s = 'States AL Date 2011 01 03 YES States MD Date 2009 08 09 NO'
```

How to substring them so that the output is:

```
'States AL Date 2011 01 03 YES', 'States MD Date 2009 08 09 NO'...
```

Each substring starts with key word "States" and has a fixed length of 30. Thx!

Comment: See `re.findall` in the standard library.

Comment: Can there be anything between them except a single space? If not, you can just use string slices.

Comment: Similar to this code for splitting a list into fixed-size slices: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use regexp search.

```
import re
s = 'States AL Date 2011 01 03 YES States MD Date 2009 08 09 NO'
results = re.findall('States [A-Z]{2} Date \d{4} \d{2} \d{2} (?:YES|NO)', s)
```

If you just want to have substrings of length 30 starting at every 'States' substring:

```
import re
s = 'States AL Date 2011 01 03 YES States MD Date 2009 08 09 NO'
results = [s[m.start():m.start()+30] for m in re.finditer('States', s)]
```

Comment: Thanks, What if they do not always end with 'yes' or 'no'? they might end up with 'T0', or 'B6'. only the length is fixed (30)

Comment: `[s[m.start():m.start()+30] for m in re.finditer('States', s)]`, but I also edited answer.